# Silverlight - Constants shared between Server-side and Client-side?

Tags: silverlight, constants

I'm developing a Silverlight (4, if that makes a difference) application, and I'm wondering if there is a way to share constants from the server side to the client side, rather than copying over a class that would contain the constants?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Create a shared assembly [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrteam/archive/2009/12/01/sharing-silverlight-assemblies-with-net-apps.aspx), and then reference it into both applications.

Or you can share code, create a file in the server side project, then add it as a LINK to the silverlight project, so it will be compiled twice. ([see here for adding as link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

I recommend the first approach if possible!